# Disable Stackdriver logging GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Google says this

> 1. Sign in to your Migrate for Compute Engine Manager with the user apiuser.
> 2. Click the System Settings icon. Set the Enable Stackdriver
> 3. Monitoring or the Enable Stackdriver Logs options to No.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.9/how-to/monitoring/disabling-stackdriver

How do I login with a user called apiuser? I went to `Migrate for Compute Engine Manager` but I don't see the `System Setting icon` either

Answer (score 1):

When you create  your migration manager, you have to define a password for `apiuser` login.

[image]

If another person did it, ask them to know the password.